# Star Rating block is not present from list of blocks or from / shortcut

Tags: block-editor

I have a GoDaddy managed WordPress site.

I'm trying to use the built-in Star Rating block as described [here](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/ratings-block), but the block is not appearing as an option.

I have verified that the WordPress version is up to date.

I've switched to different themes, like Twenty Twenty-Four in case the block wasn't compatible with the theme.

I disabled all the plugins in case a plugin was disabling the block.

I have spoken to GoDaddy support who have said nothing is wrong on their end.

I'm not sure what else to check.  Has anyone else had this trouble, or have suggestions of what to try next?

Comment: What happens when you follow [this article](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/ratings-block/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you're on GoDaddy, but you linked to a WordPress.com support article. WordPress.com is a hosting service that you would not be using if you are in fact using GoDaddy. Note that WordPress.com and the WordPress software [are different](https://wordpress.com/support/com-vs-org/). The Star Rating block is a feature of WordPress.com, and is not one of the [core blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/) included in WordPress itself.

WordPress.com develops JetPack, which makes some WordPress.com features available as a plugin. The Star Rating block [seems to be included](https://jetpack.com/support/jetpack-blocks/star-rating-block/) in the plugin as one of those features.

Comment: Ok thanks for that link and information.  I didn't realise wordpress.com and wordpress.org were different.  What confused me further is the similar [full list of blocks](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/) on wordpress.com.